# access database normalization :how to deal book volumes like 1-2 or 3-4

Tags: database-design, denormalization

my question is about NF1 what is best practice to store book volumes in table .

for example mostly it is like bookname = abc volume= 1 ect but some time it is abc volume 1-2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience it's best to have the title in its current full form. That being said, I would have the volume in the title field as simply the volume, without stating how many volumes are in the series.  "*History of Rome volume 1*"

If I put it in as "*History of Rome volume 1-2*" then if a third volume was added, I would have to update each title to account for the new number of volumes in the series.

A second approach could be adding a new field for the number of volumes in the series, which would list the total number. It would still have to be updated if a third volume was written, but is a smaller impact to update an integer field from 2 to 3, than to update the varchar field of the book title.

Comment: in table if i add volume field it will store 1-2 which in not atomic value.